# Changing from JSON to GSON / Android

Tags: android, json

So, here is my JSON (from server)

```
{
  "error": true,
  "ResultCode": 1,
}
```

I was using this code to get the info:

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
 if(!object.getBoolean("error")) Log.e("TEST", "Error is false");
 else Log.e("TEST", "Error is true");
```

Now I'm changing to GSON, but I noticed that there is nothing like "getboolean" or "getInt". How can I get my values/data ?

Comment: do you want to parse json using GSON?

Comment: what;s problem with current code?

Comment: Gson can generate java class from your JSON. So, when you do new Gson().fromJson..; you will get equivalent java class for your JSON response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to parse your json response with GSON. Create model or POJO class corresponding to json response. For example , your json response and corresponding POJO

```
class Response {
        @SerializedName("error")
        boolean error;

        @SerializedName("ResultCode")
        int resultCode;

        public boolean isError() {
            return error;
        }

        public void setError(boolean error) {
            this.error = error;
        }

        public int getResultCode() {
            return resultCode;
        }

        public void setResultCode(int resultCode) {
            this.resultCode = resultCode;
        }


    }
```

And parse json as follows :

```
   Gson gson = new Gson();
    Response response = gson.fromJson(response, Response.class);
```

Now you can get values from getter method.

For complex json, you auto generated tool for POJO http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Answer (score 0):

Quite unlike the org.json `JSONObject` et. al classes that are essentially Java representations of JSON data structures, GSON is a framework for mapping JSON to Java objects. You'd use it like this,

```
class Foo {
  int i;
  String s;
}

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
Foo f = gson.fromJson(reader, Foo.class);
```

GSON does have lower-level objects for representing JSON data strcutures but you generally don't use them unless you are doing something atypical.

Answer (score 0):

**Option1**

you define a pojo class and make:

```
String json = "{\"error\": true,\"ResultCode\": 1}";
Gson g=new Gson();
Pojo p = g.fromJson(json, Pojo.class);
p.getError();
```

**Option2:** a little more risky:

parse to json object and call the method **getAsBoolean()**

```
String json = "{\"error\": true,\"ResultCode\": 1}";
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonObject jsonObject = gson.fromJson(json, JsonObject.class);
jsonObject.get("error").getAsBoolean();
```